# Bootstrap Hamburger Menu is NOT displaying LINKS when on iPad mini

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, hamburger-menu

For large screens, the hamburger menu works perfectly (changed break point to 1200). On phones, the menu works perfectly.

On iPads, the hamburger menu shows up ok BUT when you click on it, the options do not show up!  Please help!!!  Thank you.

Here is HTML

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-fixed-top-real" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <%= link_to situations_path do %>
        <%= image_tag('A-Lister_Logo.png', class: "navbar-brand", height: '60', :alt => "A-Lister Logo") %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="hidden-sm">
          <%= link_to 'Hot Situations', situations_path %>
        </li>
        <li class="hidden-sm">
          <%= link_to 'New Situations', newest_situations_path %>
        </li>
        <li class="hidden-sm">
          <%= link_to 'A-Listers', alisters_path %>
        </li>
        <li class="hidden-sm">
          <%= link_to 'Add Situation', new_situation_path %>
        </li>
        <% if !(user_signed_in?) %>
          <li class="hidden-sm">
            <%= link_to('Become an A-Lister', new_user_registration_path)  %>
          </li>
          <li class="hidden-sm">
            <%= link_to('Login', new_lister_session_path)  %>
          </li>
        <% else %>
          <li class="hidden-sm">
            <%= link_to(("My Situations"), my_situations_path) %>
          </li>
          <li class="hidden-sm">
            <%= link_to(("Edit Account"), edit_user_registration_path) %>
          </li>
          <li class="hidden-sm">
            <%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>
          </li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div> <!-- / .navigation -->
```

Here is CSS.SCSS

```
body {
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  color: black;
  padding-top: 70px;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
        float: none !important;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
      background: white;
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top {
      top: 0;
      border-width: 0 0 1px;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
      display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
      float: none!important;
      margin-top: 7.5px;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        line-height:0;
    }
    .collapse.in{
      display:block !important;
  }
}

.navbar-fixed-top-real {
  font-size:100%;
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(222,0,32);
  max-height: 70px;
  z-index:2;
}

.navbar-nav li a {
  padding-top: 45px;
  z-index:2;
  font-size: 118%;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

All of your li classes are listed as hidden-sm, which is going to hide them on devices between desktop and mobile.  Take out this class and it'll work perfectly.